# Armazenamentos de access token (token JWT)

Tags: javascript, react, localstorage, oauth2, jwt

Estou enfrentando a necessidade de armazenar o access token de um usuário que efetuou login através de um método com OAuth2, esse token JWT será utilizado para minha aplicação de frontend, escrita em React, efetuar chamadas para uma API "em nome do usuário".

Contudo, esse dado que ao meu ver é sensível como deve ser armazenado no cliente?

Sei de algumas opções como localStorage ou cookies, mas gostaria de entender quais são os prós e contras de qualquer solução para o armazenamento desse tipo de dado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por questão de facilidade, prefiro o localStorage, no entanto os Cookies, são melhores opções por questão de segurança, ex:
é possivel configurar para que ele seja apenas enviado nas requisições Ajax sem a possibilidade de alteração com Javascript

http://www.douglaspasqua.com/2012/01/14/seguranca-cookies-httponly/

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Ai, para seu caso, você pode enviar um "setCookie" do seu backend ao efetuar o login, depois, todas as demais requisições irão enviar o cookie com o token para ser validado.

Outra coisa que você pode fazer para incrementar a segurança é, ao gerar o token, você gerar um fingerprint do usuário, algo único e gerado automaticamente, com isso você faz um doublecheck da origem da requisição

Boa sorte.